# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using .map function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting this error on the console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here's my jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).on("change","select.task_activity", function(){

  selected_activity = $("select.task_activity :selected").map(function(){ return this.value });
  //selected_activity = $("select.task_activity").val();
  new_artifact_select = $("select.new_artifact");

  /* Loads artifacts select when one or more activities are selected */
  $.post("/tasks/activity_artifacts",{
    activity_id: selected_activity
  },function(data, status){
    if (data){
      options = "";
      if (data.length > 0){
        for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          options += '<option value="'+data[i]['name']+'">'+data[i]['name']+'</option>';
        }
      }else{
        options += '<option>This activity has no artifacts</option>';
      }
    }else{
      options = '<option>Error</option>';
    }
    new_artifact_select.html(options);
  },"json");

});
```

The error triggers when the change event is caught.

Here a piece of HTML:

```
<select class="task_activity" name="task1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="35">.........</option>
  (...)
</select>
<select class="task_activity" name="task2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="36">.........</option>
  (...)
</select>
```

I need to have the selected items IDs in an array. Mapping works outside the on.("change") scope, but it looks like the browser can't accept more functions inside that one.

What are some alternatives?

Comment: Please check all the variables referenced in `$.post`. It is quite likely that one or more of the variables are not defined.

Comment: What makes you think that `.map()` is the problem? I seriously doubt it is, if that's really what your code looks like.

Comment: There's no `.map()` function in the code you posted.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena No, that's fine. I just updated my post with the full scope.

Comment: @Barmar there was a little while ago :)

Comment: Oh man, I forgot to put the main part of the code. Now I put everything @Barmar

Comment: There's a bunch of variables that should be declared with `let` or `var`, but I don't see how this code could cause that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it isn't shown how you use `selected_activity` but note that it is a jQuery object, not an array

The problem is that you are likely trying to pass it to the data of your `$.post`

To return the actual array you need to use `get()`

```
var selected_activity = $("select.task_activity :selected").map(function(){ 
   return this.value 
}).get();
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery won't just deal with this when it's making the POST query string? (I don't know because I've never tried to pass a parameter with a jQuery object as its value.)

Comment: @Pointy I think the answer is correct. I don't think there's anything in AJAX `data:` processing that treats jQuery objects specially.

Comment: @Pointy no, internally jQuery uses `$.param()` to encode objects and it chokes on jQuery objects

Comment: Ah right because there are cycles in the object graph. OK I believe it :)

Comment: @charlietfl I just updated the post. Now the whole context is there. I'll try what you suggested. That sounds weird to me though because I read somewhere .map is specially good for when you want to return an array

Comment: @Leandro the problem is that jQuery `.map()` is different from `Array.prototype.map()`. The jQuery version does not return an array.

Comment: @Leandro there are 2 different `map()` in jQuery ... `$.map()` and `$.fn.map()`. You are using `$.fn.map()` which returns jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl Now I understand. And that works. Thank you very much.